# "NameError: name 'CrossEntropyLossFlat' is not defined" when trying to import FastAI vision

Tags: python, importerror, fast-ai

After installing the latest version of the FastAI library (2.2.7) with the latest installations of torch and torchvision (1.8.0, 0.9.0 respectively), the statement `from fastai.vision.all import *` seems to return the error `NameError: name 'CrossEntropyLossFlat' is not defined`.

I just wanted to see if this was a problem with my installation, or if this was happening to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Fastai latest version is not compatible with torch 1.8, try with 1.7.1.

The fastai installation installs the correct version of torch if you hadn't it installed.